React: values from useContext won't update
I have a UserProvider that handles authentication for my Next.js application:
export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [userLoading, setUserLoading] = useState(true);

  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/user', fetchUser);

  const publicRoutes = [
    '/',
    '/login',
    '/docs',
  ];
  const isPublicRoute =
    publicRoutes.includes(router.pathname);

  // Sets user data if the user is authenticated
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.user) {
      console.log('[UserProvider] user retrieved');
      setUser(data.user);
      console.log('[UserProvider] user data set', user);
      setUserLoading(false);
    } else if (data && !data.user && !isPublicRoute) {
      setUser(null);
      setUserLoading(false);
      console.log('[UserProvider] user not retrieved');
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        router.push('/login');
      }
    } else if (error) {
      setUserLoading(false);
      console.error('[UserProvider] error', error);
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        router.push('/login');
      }
    }
  }, [data, error]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        userLoading,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

However, when I try to access the user value from a hook I've created to create my Apollo Client, the user value remains null even though I’m able to use it without issue in my functional (UI) components.
const useApolloClient = () => {
  const { user, userLoading } = useContext(UserContext);
  // Initiate client
  const [client, setClient] = useState(() => {
    return new ApolloClient({
      link: new HttpLink({
        uri: '/graphql',
      }),
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: user?.token ? `Bearer ${user.token}` : '',
      },
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const httpLink = createHttpLink({
        uri: '/graphql',
      });

      const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
        if (graphQLErrors)
          graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
            console.log(
              `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
            ),
          );
        if (networkError) console.error(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
      });

      const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
        // Ensure user data is available and valid
        if (user) {
          console.log('[ApolloClient] Token ', user.token);
        }

        if (!user) {
          console.error('[ApolloClient] User data is incomplete or not available.');
          return { headers };
        }

        return {
          headers: {
            ...headers,
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: user?.token ? `Bearer ${user.token}` : '',
          },
        };
      });

      const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
        link: authLink.concat(errorLink).concat(httpLink),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      });

      setClient(apolloClient);
    }
  }, [user, userLoading]);

  return client;
};

export default useApolloClient;

The ApolloClient is definitely wrapped within the UserProvider, so I don't think passing the data is an issue, but surely I'm doing something dumb. I currently don't store any user data in the Store/StoreProvider if that helps.
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const client = useApolloClient();

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <StoreProvider store={store}>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </StoreProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};

Here's the initialized UserContext:
export const UserContext = createContext({ login: null, user: null, token: null, userLoading: true, setUser: null});

I've tried re-writing the UserProvider, re-writing the ApolloProvider, and changing the dependencies in every respective useEffect hook, but so far, nothing seems to pass the user data through. The most similar issues seem to relate to mutating the state instead of setting new state properly via useState but I don't think I'm mutating anything here.

Did you maybe import the wrong useApolloClient hook? @apollo/client exports a hook with that name, too.

Thanks @phry I did double-check that I'm not using the version from @apollo/client, so I think it's something else.
